# Is there a way in Mercurial/TortoiseHg to remove a changeset while keeping its changes in the working copy?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, changeset

Like the title says. I essentially want a way to make Mercurial "forget" a changeset in the local repository. Obviously, this would only work for changesets which had not been pushed without also reverting the original changeset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial doesn't make forgetting anything easy -- no commands that are destructive of history are enabled by default.  Without enabling any extensions the easiest way to do this would be:

```
hg clone -U -r LAST_CHANGE_YOU_WANT your-repo new-repo
```

and then replace the .hg in `your-repo` with the one from `new-repo`.

Answer (score 1):

In this case specifically, I was trying to move changes between branches when the normal merge wouldn't work, so I used MQ, however I wanted the changes to remain in the working copy rather than accidentally getting pushed. It looks like one can do what I wanted with `hg import --no-commit`, which TortoiseHg does not currently (but should soon) provide any UI for.